# entity framework and database default values workaround

Tags: frameworks, entity, default

I have to decide about an important item and I need your help.

I'm facing an huge existing database with **a lot** of default values on **nullable** columns.

The team has to build a new MVC4 application on top of it (in fact it is a rewrite of old VB6 application).

I (as a consultant) have 'forced' the use of EF5 to get rid of all stored procedures and migrate to a more modern techology.

Now, after my research, it is clear to me that EF5 doesn't support database default values per default.  This is why my inserted records are corrupt (they are inserted because the columns are nullable, but with NULL of course).

Some options came up like using the constructor technique, setting the default values in design on the edmx, or playing around with the xml of the edmx.
Despite, these methods are not usefull for us.  Where the constructor technique looks ok for me, it is not feasible to do that for all tables in the DB.  I also have a 'njet' from the technical person because he wants to maintain these values on 1 place.  Same story for setting the default values in design.  The database is also not in our scope (read: as less as possible changes to keep existing applications running).

At this point, I'm not sure it EF is the correct choice for our project.

Is somebody aware of (3th party) tools that can fill in the database default values automatically in the generated xml of the edmx file?

Is there som more info about how this xml is build and if there is a possiblity to interfere in the process?

Is there a good readon why these default values should not be taken?  Is this going to change in a later release?

Are there other good practices that can be applied to that problem without having all values dupplicated or a massive workload?

Can I arrange something with my poco generator?

I realize there are already a lot of posts of this topic.  Too bad, there is no suitable solution for me since we have already something existing and (with all respect) an old VB6 team that I have to convince.

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Nobody?  Does that mean there is no proper solution for that problem?
Should I consider to leave the EF path?

Comment: For the record, here's the relevant ticket: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first